# [Solved]How can I enable secure boot on my laptop

Tags: windows, bios, secure-boot

I have an Asus ROG strix g513ih laptop but in BIOS menu I can't select secure boot.  It's greyed out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @emre - Your screenshots are inaccessible. Please instead use the image upload button.  Any additional screenshots provided in a comment should also be provided.  Screenshots provided by commentary are temporary

Comment: Don't put answers in the question. Instead, add an answer below. Don't forget to accept it, too, after the cooldown period is over!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!

I clicked key management under security tab in BIOS there was an option  "restore default key management" (I'm not sure exactly because when I clicked it is gone) option. I clicked it and it enabled secure boot for me.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS (UEFI) on your machine needs to be set to use UEFI and the disk setup must be GPT.

Have you set up for legacy mode?

It could be this, so then Secure Boot is disabled. Check this.

If setup properly, then:

(a) Update BIOS to see if that helps.

(b) and then contact Manufacturer Support for assistance with Secure Boot.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/21qqjhk i guess it is UEFI and my disk setup is GPT

Comment: I amended my answer to both Update BIOS and contact Manufacturer support.